# Is there a way to we customize directupdate check version on mobilefirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, mobilefirst-studio

Today we have an app in applestore with a version labeled as 7.6.2 and internal build number as 1.0.0. We are using mobilefirst 7.1 to develop. Problem is that now we have a new app, that is 7.6.2.1, but we would like to know if is possible continue to use 7.6.2 app from applestore onto 7.6.2.1 mobilefirst app (asking it because we would like to keep our customers using just a single app from applestore). We also have an app on google play and would like to apply same idea.

Maybe this is an edge case, so do we have a way to control this directupdate by ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

Customization of direct update is limited to the UI and options when you receive a direct update push.

As for version management, if both versions 7.6.2 and 7.6.2.1 are deployed in the MFP server, end users can have these versions deployed on their devices. Direct update or other configurations can be separately configured for these different versions.

However, if an end user is on v 7.6.2 and they take an update from AppStore or Playstore, and the version on the device becomes v7.6.2.1, this updated application on the device will start connecting to only v7.6.2.1 in the server. And only direct updates this version on the device ( 7.6.2.1) will receive are the ones uploaded to 7.6.2.1 in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Direct update feature is meant only to push small web resources changes into your application. If the MFP Application Version numbers for both app versions(i.e `7.6.2` and `7.6.2.1`) are different, you can continue to use both the versions and push direct update indvidually based on version number.